# Are there any potential issues caused with enabling change tracking in SQL Server 2012 on a CRM2013 Database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

We are attempting to use a service Stitch to pull out some sections of data from our CRM DB for reporting purposes. To do so I would need to enable change tracking on our CRM database and the tables I would want to pull the information from.

Generally, I shy away from do anything but reads on the CRM Database as I have read of various issues others have encountered by performing various sql tasks in sql on a CRM DB rather than using CRM for whatever the task is.

I would imagine the only consequence should be slightly larger logs while it retains the change tracking period, but was trying to determine if anyone knew of a reason not to enable change tracking on a crm database or other potential consequences.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance hit first and foremost. Also I believe the settings applied to enable change tracking will be at risk of being overwritten when you update/upgrade your CRM environment.

Since it wont be changing the base schema or performing DML on the base tables, it should be fine from a CRM Functionality perspective.